# Asterisk not playing Audio in BackGround or MP3Player APP

Tags: linux, audio, mp3, asterisk

Hi Everyone in Asterisk 18 Cooked on a Centos 7 Server when I want to play a wav file, mono pcm s16 le 8000 hz lets called MyWavFile.wav I try to play it ether way whit application BackGround or MP3Player and I'm Getting a very similar response

```
 -- Executing [112@local:1] Answer("PJSIP/5020-00000000", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [112@local:2] BackGround("PJSIP/5020-00000000", "/var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav") in new stack
[Jul 12 23:26:49] WARNING[8272][C-00000001]: file.c:824 ast_openstream_full: File /var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav does not exist in any format
[Jul 12 23:26:49] WARNING[8272][C-00000001]: file.c:1303 ast_streamfile: Unable to open /var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav (format (ulaw)): No such file or directory
[Jul 12 23:26:49] WARNING[8272][C-00000001]: pbx_builtins.c:1256 pbx_builtin_background: ast_streamfile failed on PJSIP/5020-00000000 for /var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav
    -- Executing [112@local:3] Hangup("PJSIP/5020-00000000", "") in new stack
```

```
    -- Executing [112@local:1] Answer("PJSIP/5020-00000001", "") in new stack
    -- Executing [112@local:2] MP3Player("PJSIP/5020-00000001", "/var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav") in new stack
[Jul 12 23:27:42] WARNING[8288][C-00000002]: app_mp3.c:258 mp3_exec: MP3 stream '/var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav' is broken or nonexistent
    -- Executing [112@local:3] Hangup("PJSIP/5020-00000001", "") in new stack
```

but if I use that same file as MOH it works it plays MMMM what it should be lacking on this ?

Thank you all for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is multi-format PBX. File may end not by .wav, but .g729 or .gsm

Can be more than one file with same name and asterisk will  choose one based on codec path.

So.
This

```
Executing [112@local:2] BackGround("PJSIP/5020-00000000", "/var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile.wav") in new stack
```

SHOULD NOT work. You have put filename WITHOUT extensions like this

```
exten => 112,2,BackGround(/var/lib/asterisk/moh/MyWavFile)
```

ps in your case, codec is ulaw and it will search like -> .ulaw ->.sln ->.wav -> .alaw -> .WAV(gsm) -> .gsm etc.

Comment: It Works in BackGround but not in MP3Player but it's enough for me :P Thanks

Comment: Mp3 player can play MP3 only.

Comment: I try in MP3Player whit a mp3 file but still the same and I have compiled doing `/contrib/scripts/get_mp3_source.sh` and it says it was correct in the compiled whit Mp3 but still not playing  any ways at the moment I gave not much interest in playing MP3 just was tryig to play in some how an i did thank to you ! @arheops thank you ;)

Comment: I was trying to send a recording to ether way an extension or a conferences and i did